# Windows activition after boot drive change

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, ssd, motherboard, license-key

Recently I have bought a new SSD , I'm trying to boot from that SSD I had the installation disk of a legit version of Windows 7 that I upgraded from to Windows 10 but unfortunately the sticker with the product key is damaged. right now I have Windows 10 with a digital licence connected to my Microsoft account . 
If I will install an unactive version of Windows 10 on my SSD will it be active because the digital licence is saved on the actual Mother board or will I be able to activate it using my Microsoft account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reinstall the same edition of Windows 10 that your device has a digital license for without entering a product key.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12440/windows-10-activation
According to following link, if you link you digital license with your Microsoft account, you could use the Activation troubleshooter to reactivate Windows after a significant hardware change.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/20530/windows-10-reactivating-after-hardware-change